# how to us if..else..statement in dplyr chaining in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My question is how to us if..else..statement in dplyr chaining?
For example:

```
select.vars <- function(data, price=TRUE ){
    diamonds %>% {if (price) select(price) else select(carat)}
}
select.vars(diamonds)
```

I got error:

```
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

This is a meaningless function. Just for illustration purpose...
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `if/else` within the `select`

```
select.vars <- function(data, price=TRUE){
     diamonds %>% 
              select(if(price) "price" else "carat")
 }

resprice <-  select.vars(diamonds)
rescarat <- select.vars(diamonds, FALSE)
head(rescarat)
# A tibble: 6 x 1
#  carat
#  <dbl>
#1  0.23
#2  0.21
#3  0.23
#4  0.29
#5  0.31
#6  0.24

head(resprice)
# A tibble: 6 x 1
#  price
#  <int>
#1   326
#2   326
#3   327
#4   334
#5   335
#6   336
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Simply add the .for each select.

```
select.vars <- function(data, price=TRUE ){
    diamonds %>% {if (price) select(., price) else select(., carat)}
}
```